# Node.js dns.resolve not returning correct IP address

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm trying to use [Node.js DNS resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback) to look up an IP address of a domain that belong to me (let's call it host.mydomain.com). If the lookup for `host.mydomain.com` is done from the server that host.mydomain.com actually points to, it returns the server's local NIC IP address (`192.168.0.10`) instead of the server's external IP address.

Doing a host lookup for `host.mydomain.com` from an external machine using the same code returns the expected external IP address. More importantly, I have a different server in another environment, call it `host.otherdomain.com`, that does correctly return its own external IP address when doing a lookup, using the same code.

I do not have anything in my hosts file that would override this. Both domains are from the same DNS provider, and both are wildcard domains.

My code:

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers([ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ]);

domain="host.mydomain.com";

dns.resolve(domain, function (error, addresses) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);  // null
    console.log("DNS servers: ", dns.getServers());  // [ '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4' ]
    console.log(domain + " resolves to: ", addresses);  // [ '192.168.0.10' ]
});
```

I'm currently using Node.js 6 on all servers.

Comment: You said your code is working in another environment. So the issue probably lies with your environment not your code. Is it possible that 8.8.8.8 is routing to an internal DNS server in your particular environment. Do you get the same issue when trying other Public DNS Servers? (see https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062).

Comment: when you do a dig on your domain from your internal server, what do you get? with the dig, check the resolver at the bottom that is providing the answer. If it isn't Google, redo the dig with @8.8.8.8.  there might not be anything explicit in your hostfile, but it sounds like you've got something configured in the resolution path causing this issue.

Comment: @KMo It does seem likely now that our DNS is being hijacked by something, yes. The server is in an IBM datacenter and I've since sent them a support request. The same problems occur when using other DNS servers. Both `nslookup mydomain.com dns_ip` and `dig mydomain.com @dns_ip` returns the local NIC address, regardless of which IP I try.

Comment: @Renée `dig @8.8.8.8 mydomain.com` returns the same results, unfortunately. Have tried several other DNS IPs as well with the same results.

Comment: does your code give you non-local IPs if you try to look up something that is not your local domain? something common or your other known domain? is your nameserver external to this machine? if yes, then i'd do a packet capture to see what really crossed the interface. if no, then suspect something in one of the zone or general conf files.

Comment: @Renée Any domain that does not point to the local server resolves correctly, and any domain that points to the local server is resolved as the internal NIC's IP. This is regardless of which DNS servers I specify. Everything resolves correctly in my personal networks. I unfortunately have no control over the DNS as it's (apparently) built into the datacenter infrastructure. At this stage I am still waiting for IBM support to provide a solution. I'll likely end up answering my own question with work-arounds. The packet capture is good advice - I will try when I have a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem turned out to be with the IBM datacenter where the machine was hosted. It was running on a modded vCenter setup their staff had set up, and was doing funky things with DNS. I know vCenter has Linux guest integration, I'm unsure if this was part of the problem.

So in short I guess the solution is to ensure your environment (in my case the datacenter) isn't messing you around.